# Move an image above another tag

Tags: html, css

In the HTML here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  body { padding-top:110px;background-color: powderblue;}
  .top
  {
    position:-110px;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <menu>
  <menuitem> Home</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 1</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 2</menuitem>
  </menu>
  <img src="top.jpg" class="top"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the image to be shown above the menu purely by CSS. For some reason I cannot explain I can't move the image tag above the menu.
How to do it in CSS style definition?

Comment: so you have constraints to not be able to modify the HTML? there are several things you are doing very wrong. You applied `position` to an element, which is positioned static. This will have no effect. Also the html image tag is wrong. <img /> is a singleton element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 2 ways to do this. Either `Flexbox` in combination with `flex-order` or `CSS-Grid` in combination with `grid-templates`.

**Flexbox solution:**

apply: `body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` to conevert it into a flexbox and place the items below each other like normal block level lements. Then use flex-order on the items to define in which roder they should be placed. `.top { order: 1; } menu { order: 2; }`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  order: 1;
}

menu {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <menuitem> Home</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 1</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 2</menuitem>
</menu>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.jpg" class="top">
```

**CSS-Grid solution:**

Apply a grid to the body: `body { display: grid }`. Then define the grid-areas with: `.top { grid-area: image; } menu { grid-area: menu; }`. Use `body {grid-template-areas: "image" "menu"; }` to place the image above the menu.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "image"
    "menu";
}

.top {
  grid-area: image;
}

menu {
  grid-area: menu;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <menuitem> Home</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 1</menuitem>
  <menuitem> Menu 2</menuitem>
</menu>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.jpg" class="top">
```

Comment: Grid approach looks promising. Let me test it out.

Answer (score 2):

CSS and HTML go hand in hand. Sometimes it's better to redo our html to match what we want vs trying to make CSS do something it's not meant to do.

That doesn't answer your question though. There are always multiple ways to do something, but the simplest solution is to use display:flex;

Flex is for managing rows/columns of elements. There's a great article on css-tricks about them https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

```html
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 110px;
            background-color: powderblue;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }
    </style>
```

Will work for changing the order of the menu and image

Comment: flexbox is the right approach but thats about it. What you do is not only placing the image on top but reversing the order. means the menu items are not ordered correctly anymore. You shoul have used flex-order instead.

Comment: Will this alter the positioning of any elements that will be added to the page?

Comment: exactly all the elements will be placed in reverse direction. so element `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` will be placed `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1` instead. Thats why flex-order should be used so you can place the items like: `2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4`

Comment: I was not aware of flex order reversing effects of column-reverse. That's an important aspect to consider when using it as a solution. Thanks for correcting and clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

u can achieve that using flexBox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { padding-top:110px;background-color: powderblue;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    }
.top
{
    position:-110px;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<menu>
<menuitem> Home</menuitem>
<menuitem> Menu 1</menuitem>
<menuitem> Menu 2</menuitem>
</menu>
<img src="top.jpg" class="top"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add explanation of the solution you are suggesting. This adds value to the solution in long term perspective.

Comment: flexbox is the right approach but thats about it. What you do is not only placing the image on top but reversing the order. Means all items are not ordered correctly anymore but in reverse order. You should have used flex-order instead.